# Application.forms.Count is Sometimes Inaccurate

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been using Application.forms.Count to measure the number of forms that are open, and most of the time, this function works correctly. However, every once in a while, the count is wrong.

When I view the amount in a MsgBox, Access thinks that there are 2 forms open when it is obvious that only 1 is open. I have this running on my Form_Unload method, as the form should only close if it is the last form still open. I have made sure that there are no other instances of Access running when this is performed and no pop-ups or modals are open.

```
Dim Form As Double

Form = Application.forms.Count
MsgBox Form

If Form = 1 Then
'Nothing, form closes
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes
Else
MsgBox "You cannot close this form right now."
cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

As mentioned, this code does work most of the time, but it is a major hindrance when the wrong count occurs, and I'd like to find out what is causing it.

Comment: First: You should not Name the variable `Form` as this is an object type. Second: When Access "counts wrong" and says 2 instead of the expected 1, then check the names of the forms in the Forms collection (`Debug.Print Forms(0).Name` and `Debug.Print Forms(1).Name`).

Comment: Alright, I've changed the variable to formCount. I will update this topic again once I encounter the issue again and I'll try what you've recommended.

Comment: Also, the `Forms.Count` method returns a `Long`, not a `Double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all this time, I believe I've found the root of this error. I did not previously know that forms could be opened in the background without actually appearing, and this happens when you read or write a project-level variable. I had checked on a variable and then tried to check the number of forms up, and there was two open despite only one being visible. I think a simple DoCmd.Close "formNameHere" after checking on the variable would be the best way to go about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using (Debug.Print Forms(0).Name and Debug.Print Forms(1).Name), I was able to figure out that the form I had open had somehow duplicated itself (though only one version of the form is open on the screen). While I have no idea how this happened, a simple restart of MS Access will get rid of the duplication. I'll add this supplemental if statement to prevent this in the future:

```
If formCount = 1 Then
...
Else
 If Forms(0).Name = Forms(1).Name Then
 'The duplication error is happening again
 DoCmd.Close "FormNameHere"
 End If
End If
```